# What book features aliens defeating humanity with a sleep inducing virus?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, alien-invasion

What I remember of the plot is that aliens called Poppers (or something similar) have landed on Earth and released a virus that has put the human population to sleep. Only about one in a hundred thousand or a million people are immune and are still awake and functioning.

After these few people spend a couple hundred pages running around trying to figure out a strategy for fighting back, the book ends with the fact that the aliens come from a very cold planet and are going to settle at the poles. They only put everyone to sleep while sorting things out on earth, and plan to coexist peaceful with humans.

The book was written in the 1960’s or earlier.

Comment: Consider improving the question title to be more "unique". If identification questions are to stick, we don't want them all with the same title: "I don't remember the name of this story"

Comment: I changed your title, if you don't like it feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 8):

The novel [***Alien Invasion and Other Inconveniences***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1155548) by [**Brian Yansky**](http://www.brianyansky.com/) has everything you describe but was published in 2010.

There's no wikipedia article for it, but I found an [amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076364384X) that describes it:

> Most of humanity goes quietly to sleep
> and never wakes, but a few people with
> latent telepathic gifts become slaves
> who are forced to remake Earth to
> Sanginian standards.

Comment: [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/) has near-complete bibliographic data on written SF (novels, short stories, collections, and some essays; no comics).

Comment: Book I'm asking about had more of a "happy" ending.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt TheMoot will be back but... for the sake of clearing up old queries. I do believe this is *Sleeping Planet* (1965) by William Burkett Jr.

The publication time frame also fits and the plot is a direct match. Also, the aliens have a nickname. Not Poppers but "Larrys". To whit:

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20625439-sleeping-planet?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=mKejmbHkEw&rank=2):

> Science Fiction Encyclopedia described this as a “hard-edged” tale of the 24th-century conquest of Earth by an alien empire the humans had judged too stupid to pull off such a coup. **Only a handful of humans escaped the effects of a mutated narcoleptic drug that put humanity into protracted hibernation**. The battle to liberate Earth is fought by those few with the aid of a vengeful ghost called “Gremper” by the aliens. The action is fast and furious, while the genius general of the invading fleet goes slowly insane at the disruption of his well-laid plans.

Answer (score 1):

Sleepwalker's World by Gordon R Dickson is about a power source which puts everyone to sleep, and a group who learn to not fall asleep, and discover some sort of conspiracy (i think) but the rest is pretty hazy, really, sorry.